# What happens if node js doesn't find a client html file?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, socket.io

AM trying to implement a push server for my pHP application.
My initial thoughts were as long as i keep the EVENTS called on my client let say message_view.php file . I would not have a problem of emiting node js events.

**But i see that most of the tutorial online use something like I dont understood this ?**

```
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/client.html') ...//html files
    or 
    response.sendfile('hello world')
```

After they have started the server. Then they add event and logic as follow on the client html file that am supposed to do it on my messages_view.php file.

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

and socket emiting events like this one :

```
<script>

// create a new websocket
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000/?profile_id=abcde2');
//..I want to code here to update my  divs.
</script>
```

What do i need exactly to emit this message on my PHP file. Many Thanks!

Comment: Do you create a server in node?

Comment: Yes Sir. I have created the server the only thing i want is to emit those ebents from y PHp file

Comment: It seems a bit unclear to me, but, if you're asking if you need to serve .html to be able to use websockets, the answer would be no.

Comment: why it was unclear ? am asking to serve php file without sending them with send file ?

Comment: that's unclear too... what is send file? how does php tie into this? to me it seems like php is irrelevant in your question.

Comment: response.sendfile('hello world') or response.readFIle thing

Comment: and... that's node.js code to send a file? you don't need that for a socket server unless the socket server needs to also serve html. It seems you don't want that, and want to instead serve html with php.

Comment: Yes can node and php communicate by just simply importing the script  on my page. socket.io js file ? some also do it like the full path with server address forexample http://localhost:3000/socket.io.js smthng

Comment: Yes, just make sure you use the correct url to the socket server.

Comment: please can you state that on the answer so that ic an follow later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to serve html with php, and have a node.js socket server, the socket server doesn't need to serve html, so you can omit the majority of the example you're using. Just include the script in your .php that serves the html page and  make sure the url to the script properly targets the socket server.

Comment: Thanks! is it the actual server code or the socket.io file ? ex.server.js

Comment: the socket.io js file that the example includes in the .html file.